# Select Option with ngFor in Angular is showing duplicate values, API returns values with the same department id for different employee

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu

Select option with `ngFor` in Angular is showing duplicate values, API returns values with the same department ID for different employees.

This is my HTML snippet, this just gets the data and shows it in the select option dropdown:

```
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="departmentId" id="department" name="department">
                                        <option value='' disabled selected hidden>Select 
     Department</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let data of attendanceLogs" [value]="data.id"> 
   {{data.department_name}}</option> 
                                    </select>   


         getAttendanceLog(){
            this.hrService.getAttendanceLogs().subscribe(data => {
              if(data.status_code == 200) {
               this.attendanceLogs = data.data;

               this.rows = this.attendanceLogs;
               this.temp = this.attendanceLogs;

                } else {
               this.snotifyService.error(data.message)
             }
           },
           error => {
             this.snotifyService.error("Not able to load the data. Please reload project and try again.");    
          });

        };
```

Comment: By any chance, are you modifying `rows` or `temp` anywhere? As that would also affect `attendenceLogs`.

Comment: i passed to rows to populate my tables, while temp is used for filtering the data stored on the page. this is the code where temp is used .               
              updateFilter(event) {
  const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
  // filter our data
  const temp = this.temp.filter(function (d) {
    return d.english_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
  });
  // update the rows
  this.rows = temp;
  // Whenever the filter changes, always go back to the first page
  this.table.offset = 0;
  };